# What should be the output of the pdf for multivariate normal distrubition?

Tags: gaussian

Let's think we have a multivariate normal distribution with 
$$\mathbf x_1=\begin{bmatrix}x_{11}\\x_{12}\end{bmatrix},\quad \mathbf x_2=\begin{bmatrix}x_{21}\\x_{22}\end{bmatrix},\quad\mathbf m=\begin{bmatrix}m_1\\m_2\end{bmatrix}, \quad\text{and}\quad\mathbf S.$$ 
Where $\mathbf m$ is the mean, and $\mathbf S$ is a $2\times 2$ covariance matrix.

- What should the result of the PDF be? Should it be a $2\times 1$ array or a single value?
- Can  any of its values be bigger than $1$?

Comment: What is $x$, what is $m$ and what is $S$ defining?

Comment: Doesn't [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Density_function) answer your question? And if not, please explain what is still unclear.

Comment: @Maximilian is probably feature, m is mean and S is coveriance matrix.

Comment: @Matt Sort of, the thing that confuses my mind is every x has also 2 values.

Comment: Wouldn't that just be a 4-dimensional distribution? Why are the elements $x_{ij}$ grouped in such a way?

Comment: @Matt I can give an example of it. Lets think you have 100 laptops. You want to find if a laptop is broken or not. x is a point in your  graphic card x11 shows broken card volt values and x12 shows fine card volt values. And x2 is a point in your sound card where x21,x22 is the same thing for sound card.

Comment: But the voltage values of the graphic card have nothing to do with the voltage values of the sound card. So why a joint distribution? What do you want to do with that distribution?

Comment: @Matt it is for getting better probability. Lets think that only testing your graphic card you will get some error where in a voltage value there is both fine and broken cards. So you take a second feature in this case sound card to lower this error.

Comment: I understand, but how exactly are you going to do this with a multivariate Gaussian distribution?

Comment: It seems I can't. Thanks for letting me figuring out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PDF $p$ of a, say, bivariate Normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and covariance $S$ is a function that takes two parameters and has a scalar-valued output:

$$ p: \mathbb{R}^2 \mapsto \mathbb{R}$$

and is given by

$$p(x_1,x_2) = \frac{1}{2\pi |S|}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}(\vec{x}-\vec{\mu})^TS^{-1}(\vec{x}-\vec{\mu})\right)$$

where $\vec{\mu}\in\mathbb{R}^2$ is the mean of the distribution and $S\in\mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$ is its covariance matrix. $\vec{x}=[x_1, x_2]^T$ is the function input and $p(x_1, x_2)$ is the function output.

So, the output is a scalar (a single value). Furthermore, the PDF can become larger than one for some input $\vec{x}$.